# Animated bar graph not showing transitions, only key frames in Plotly.js

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I have been attempting to animate a stacked bar graph with three datasets using Plotly.js using the `addFrames` function. I want to animate the length of the bar (the x-value) and the width of the bar. Unfortunately, nothing renders on the screen unless I use `redraw: true` to force a redraw at the end of each frame. And then, it just renders the frames that I set up with no transition.

To create the script, I mostly referred to [this example](https://plot.ly/javascript/animations/#animating-sequences-of-frames) on the Plotly website.

Here is the snippet:

```js
//Load in data
var supply = [
  [280, 720, 476.6666667, 876.4705882, 650, 736.6666667, 1831.333333, 1005.714286, 390, 462.3529412, 0, 611.4102564, 800, 526.5217391, 503.030303, 543.6111111, 1023.529412, 1360, 1980, 1651.612903, 1000, 1760, 886.6666667, 0, 0, 0, 2220],
  [280, 720, 476.6666667, 876.4705882, 650, 736.6666667, 1831.333333, 1025.357143, 390, 462.3529412, 0, 760, 800, 526.5217391, 503.030303, 543.6111111, 1200, 1360, 1800, 1920, 1000, 1760, 886.6666667, 0, 0, 0, 2220],
  [280, 720, 476.6666667, 876.4705882, 650, 736.6666667, 1831.333333, 1056.785714, 390, 462.3529412, 0, 760, 800, 538.6956522, 527.2727273, 435.4166667, 1200, 1360, 1800, 1920, 1000, 2053.333333, 886.6666667, 0, 0, 0, 2220],
  [280, 900, 476.6666667, 900, 879.5454545, 487.5, 1831.333333, 1056.785714, 390, 462.3529412, 0, 760, 800, 523.4782609, 527.2727273, 527.7777778, 1200, 900, 1800, 1800, 1000, 2170.666667, 886.6666667, 0, 0, 1350, 1350],
  [280, 900, 476.6666667, 900, 1350, 487.5, 1831.333333, 937.5, 390, 575, 390, 785.4166667, 0, 504.1666667, 750, 595.5882353, 900, 900, 1800, 1800, 1000, 2170.666667, 886.6666667, 0, 0, 1350, 1350],
  [420, 900, 476.6666667, 900, 1350, 487.5, 1831.333333, 937.5, 390, 575, 390, 900, 0, 504.1666667, 750, 595.5882353, 900, 900, 1800, 1800, 900, 900, 837.5, 525, 1350, 1350, 1350],
  [548.5714286, 900, 476.6666667, 900, 1350, 487.5, 1831.333333, 937.5, 390, 641.6666667, 390, 900, 0, 496.1538462, 750, 767.6470588, 900, 900, 1800, 1800, 900, 900, 900, 900, 1350, 1350, 1350],
  [720, 900, 476.6666667, 900, 1350, 900, 1640, 900, 390, 725, 390, 900, 0, 487.5, 750, 767.6470588, 900, 900, 1800, 1800, 900, 1050, 900, 900, 1350, 1350, 1350],
  [720, 900, 880, 900, 1350, 900, 1640, 900, 390, 725, 390, 900, 0, 900, 750, 767.6470588, 900, 900, 1800, 1800, 900, 1050, 900, 900, 1350, 1350, 1350],
  [720, 900, 880, 900, 1350, 900, 1640, 900, 540, 825, 540, 900, 0, 900, 825, 833.8235294, 900, 900, 1800, 1800, 900, 1050, 900, 900, 1350, 1350, 1350],
  [720, 900, 880, 900, 1350, 900, 1640, 900, 540, 700, 540, 900, 0, 0, 900, 900, 900, 900, 1800, 1800, 900, 1050, 900, 900, 1350, 1350, 1350],
  [720, 900, 880, 900, 1350, 900, 1640, 900, 540, 700, 540, 900, 0, 0, 900, 900, 900, 900, 1800, 1800, 900, 1050, 900, 900, 1350, 1350, 1350],
  [720, 900, 880, 900, 1350, 900, 1640, 900, 540, 700, 540, 900, 0, 0, 900, 900, 900, 900, 1800, 1800, 900, 1050, 900, 900, 1350, 1350, 1350],
  [720, 900, 880, 900, 1350, 900, 1640, 900, 540, 700, 540, 900, 0, 0, 900, 900, 900, 900, 1800, 1800, 900, 1050, 900, 900, 1350, 1350, 1350]
];

var demand = [
  [221.3333333, 571.6666667, 391.3333333, 886, 108.6666667, 611, 1142.333333, 945.6666667, 221, 557.3333333, 0, 500.6666667, 568.3333333, 576.6666667, 550, 418.6666667, 820.6666667, 706, 1331.333333, 904, 979.6666667, 1176, 511, 0, 0, 0, 1384.666667],
  [299.7553333, 552.4706667, 419.5093333, 895.267, 159.3846667, 622.133, 1244.153333, 1086.046667, 222.2333, 530.5553333, 0, 571.1776667, 619.2893333, 580.1646667, 560.267, 447.7106667, 1059.226667, 810.73, 1333.155633, 1044.47, 1164.106667, 1347.2, 679.87, 0, 0, 0, 1240.306667],
  [378.1773333, 533.2746667, 447.6853333, 904.534, 210.1026667, 633.266, 1345.973333, 1226.426667, 223.4666, 503.7773333, 0, 641.6886667, 670.2453333, 583.6626667, 570.534, 476.7546667, 1297.786667, 915.46, 1334.977933, 1184.94, 1348.546667, 1518.4, 848.74, 0, 0, 0, 1095.946667],
  [456.6, 690.6, 480, 901.8, 552, 631.68, 1447.8, 1366.8, 218.82, 477, 0, 712.2, 712.2, 587.16, 580.8, 505.8, 1536.36, 691.8, 1410, 1233, 1533, 1689.6, 1017.6, 0, 0, 775.74, 814.8],
  [472.44, 708.12, 501.12, 915.72, 580.56, 702.492, 1413, 1420.32, 218.148, 546, 422.16, 882.96, 0, 588.888, 1007.58, 613.56, 1623.384, 701.868, 1420.32, 1262.508, 1475.4, 1567.8, 1052.28, 0, 0, 819.588, 1106.16],
  [805.44, 725.64, 522.24, 929.64, 609.12, 773.304, 1340.64, 1430.64, 217.476, 572.88, 418.92, 875.52, 0, 573.816, 1011.36, 639.72, 1717.968, 711.936, 1430.64, 1292.016, 1011.24, 1586.64, 786.408, 1086.96, 409.08, 863.436, 1397.52],
  [845.16, 743.16, 543.36, 943.56, 637.68, 844.116, 1337.76, 1440.96, 216.804, 599.76, 415.68, 868.08, 0, 558.744, 1015.14, 665.88, 1812.552, 722.004, 1440.96, 1321.524, 1016.76, 1488.96, 751.212, 1121.64, 613.62, 907.284, 1688.88],
  [884.88, 760.68, 564.48, 957.48, 666.24, 914.928, 1334.88, 1451.28, 216.132, 626.64, 412.44, 860.64, 0, 543.672, 1018.92, 692.04, 1907.136, 732.072, 1451.28, 1351.032, 1022.28, 1391.28, 716.016, 1156.32, 818.16, 951.132, 1980.24],
  [924.6, 778.2, 585.6, 971.4, 694.8, 985.74, 1332, 1461.6, 215.46, 653.52, 409.2, 853.2, 0, 528.6, 1022.7, 718.2, 2001.72, 742.14, 1461.6, 1380.54, 1027.8, 1293.6, 680.82, 1191, 1022.7, 994.98, 2271.6],
  [958.8, 766.44, 601.44, 977.64, 727.92, 999.432, 1387.656, 1502.928, 218.688, 691.992, 412.56, 861, 0, 528.6, 1018.5, 743.16, 2012.22, 749.712, 1498.56, 1438.08, 1069.8, 1304.64, 737.856, 1184.76, 1030.596, 1002.024, 2284.2],
  [993, 754.68, 617.28, 983.88, 761.04, 1013.124, 1443.312, 1544.256, 221.916, 730.464, 415.92, 868.8, 0, 0, 1014.3, 768.12, 2022.72, 757.284, 1535.52, 1495.62, 1111.8, 1315.68, 794.892, 1178.52, 1038.492, 1009.068, 2296.8],
  [1027.2, 742.92, 633.12, 990.12, 794.16, 1026.816, 1498.968, 1585.584, 225.144, 768.936, 419.28, 876.6, 0, 0, 1010.1, 793.08, 2033.22, 764.856, 1572.48, 1553.16, 1153.8, 1326.72, 851.928, 1172.28, 1046.388, 1016.112, 2309.4],
  [1061.4, 731.16, 648.96, 996.36, 827.28, 1040.508, 1554.624, 1626.912, 228.372, 807.408, 422.64, 884.4, 0, 0, 1005.9, 818.04, 2043.72, 772.428, 1609.44, 1610.7, 1195.8, 1337.76, 908.964, 1166.04, 1054.284, 1023.156, 2322],
  [1095.6, 719.4, 664.8, 1002.6, 860.4, 1054.2, 1610.28, 1668.24, 231.6, 845.88, 426, 892.2, 0, 0, 1001.7, 843, 2054.22, 780, 1646.4, 1668.24, 1237.8, 1348.8, 966, 1159.8, 1062.18, 1030.2, 2334.6]
];

var freq = [
  [4, 6, 7.333333333, 10, 10, 11.33333333, 13.66666667, 11, 6, 6, 0, 6.333333333, 6.666666667, 7, 6.666666667, 6.333333333, 10, 11.33333333, 11, 10.66666667, 8.333333333, 14.66666667, 12.66666667, 0, 0, 0, 12.33333333],
  [4, 6, 7.333333333, 10, 10, 11.33333333, 13.66666667, 11, 6, 6, 0, 6.333333333, 6.666666667, 7, 6.666666667, 6.333333333, 10, 11.33333333, 10, 10.66666667, 8.333333333, 14.66666667, 12.66666667, 0, 0, 0, 12.33333333],
  [4, 6, 7.333333333, 10, 10, 11.33333333, 13.66666667, 11, 6, 6, 0, 6.333333333, 6.666666667, 7, 6.666666667, 6.333333333, 10, 11.33333333, 10, 10.66666667, 8.333333333, 14.66666667, 12.66666667, 0, 0, 0, 12.33333333],
  [4, 7.5, 7.333333333, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 13.66666667, 11, 6, 6, 0, 6.333333333, 6.666666667, 7, 6.666666667, 6.333333333, 10, 7.5, 10, 10, 8.333333333, 14.66666667, 12.66666667, 0, 0, 7.5, 7.5],
  [4, 7.5, 7.333333333, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 13.66666667, 7.5, 6, 7.5, 6, 7.5, 0, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 10, 10, 8.333333333, 14.66666667, 12.66666667, 0, 0, 7.5, 7.5],
  [6, 7.5, 7.333333333, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 13.66666667, 7.5, 6, 7.5, 6, 7.5, 0, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 10, 10, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5],
  [6, 7.5, 7.333333333, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 13.66666667, 7.5, 6, 7.5, 6, 7.5, 0, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 10, 10, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5],
  [6, 7.5, 7.333333333, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 13.66666667, 7.5, 6, 7.5, 6, 7.5, 0, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 10, 10, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5],
  [6, 7.5, 7.333333333, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 13.66666667, 7.5, 6, 7.5, 6, 7.5, 0, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 10, 10, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5],
  [6, 7.5, 7.333333333, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 13.66666667, 7.5, 6, 7.5, 6, 7.5, 0, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 10, 10, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5],
  [6, 7.5, 7.333333333, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 13.66666667, 7.5, 6, 7.5, 6, 7.5, 0, 0, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 10, 10, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5],
  [6, 7.5, 7.333333333, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 13.66666667, 7.5, 6, 7.5, 6, 7.5, 0, 0, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 10, 10, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5],
  [6, 7.5, 7.333333333, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 13.66666667, 7.5, 6, 7.5, 6, 7.5, 0, 0, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 10, 10, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5],
  [6, 7.5, 7.333333333, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 13.66666667, 7.5, 6, 7.5, 6, 7.5, 0, 0, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 10, 10, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5]
];

//Prepare the stack values
var usedSupply = [];
var excessSupply = [];
var excessDemand = [];
for (let a = 0; a < supply.length; a++) {
  let usTemp = [];
  let esTemp = [];
  let edTemp = [];
  for (let b = 0; b < supply[a].length; b++) {
    if (supply[a][b] > demand[a][b]) usTemp.push(demand[a][b]);
    else usTemp.push(supply[a][b]);
    if (supply[a][b] - demand[a][b] > 0) esTemp.push(supply[a][b] - demand[a][b]);
    else esTemp.push(0);
    if (demand[a][b] - supply[a][b] > 0) edTemp.push(demand[a][b] - supply[a][b]);
    else edTemp.push(0);
  }
  usedSupply.push(usTemp);
  excessSupply.push(esTemp);
  excessDemand.push(edTemp);
}

//Prepare the y-axis tick locations
var tickSum = 0;
var tickVals = [];
for (let a = 0; a < freq.length; a++) {
  tickVals.push(15 * a + 7.5);
}

//Prepare the initial graph data
var trace0 = {
  name: 'Used Supply',
  type: 'bar',
  x: usedSupply[0],
  y: tickVals,
  width: freq[0],
  orientation: "h",
  marker: {
    color: '#cccccc',
    opacity: '1.0'
  }
}
var trace1 = {
  name: 'Excess Supply',
  type: 'bar',
  x: excessSupply[0],
  y: tickVals,
  width: freq[0],
  orientation: "h",
  marker: {
    color: '#00ff00',
    opacity: '0.5'
  }
}
var trace2 = {
  name: 'Excess Demand',
  type: 'bar',
  x: excessDemand[0],
  y: tickVals,
  width: freq[0],
  orientation: "h",
  marker: {
    color: '#ff0000',
    opacity: '0.5'
  }
}

var data = [trace0, trace1, trace2]

//Prepare the layout object
var layout = {
  barmode: 'stack',
  yaxis: {
    tickvals: tickVals
  }
}

//Generate key frames for animation
let frames = [];
let frameNames = [];
for (let a = 0; a < usedSupply.length; a++) {
  frames.push({
    name: 'frame' + a,
    x: excessSupply[a],
    width: freq[a]
  });
  frameNames.push('frame' + a);
}

//Load the plot and animate

Plotly.plot('plotly-div', data, layout, {
  showSendToCloud: true,
  responsive: true
}).then(function() {
  Plotly.addFrames('plotly-div', frames);
}).then(function() {
  Plotly.animate('plotly-div', frameNames, {
    transition: {
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'linear'
    },
    frame: {
      duration: 500,
      redraw: false
    },
    mode: 'afterall'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>


<!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this div -->
<div id="plotly-div"></div>
```

I also tried removing the `width` property from the frames to see if that was causing issues. I also tried adding `y` values (which don't change) but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As at the time of writing, it is not possible to animate a bar graph using Plot.ly yet. Hiding in the [documentation](https://plot.ly/javascript/animations/#animating-the-data) is this line:

> Currently, only scatter traces may be smoothly transitioned from one state to the next. Other traces are compatible with frames and animations but will be updated instantaneously.

This should change soon. Already, there are [commits](https://github.com/darabos/plotly.js/pulls) awaiting to be merged into the master to allow bar graphs to animate. Hopefully, this answer can be updated with a working solution in the near future. If you are confident building your own version of Plot.ly, you could build [this](https://github.com/darabos/plotly.js/tree/darabos-animated-bars) forked version to animate bar charts now.